# Creating Javascript Buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created buttons using javascript, these buttons are created onload by the javascript page. The number of buttons created, as well as the button attributes (id, name), depend on the info that is fetched from a database table. Now I need to use the buttons independently, but I don't know the id in advance so I could mention it on any function, please help.

```
var CABLE_BOM_ALT_QUERY_PAGE = 'GetAltFromBom.json.aspx';

var WIRE_TYPE = 'AVSSXF2B';
var WIRE_LENGTH = 2000;

$(document).ready(function () {
    FetchCableBom();
});

function FetchCableBom() {
    $.ajax({
        url: CABLE_BOM_ALT_QUERY_PAGE
      , data: "WireType=" + WIRE_TYPE + "&WireLength=" + WIRE_LENGTH
      , dataType: 'json'
      , success: DisplayButtons
      , error: ErrorHandler
      , async: false
    });
}

function createButtons(tbID, tbClass, tbType, tbValue, onClick) {
    return '\n<input'
        + (tbID ? ' id=\'' + tbID + '\'' : '')
        + (tbClass ? ' class=\'' + tbClass + '\'' : '')
        + (tbType ? ' type=\'' + tbType + '\'' : '')
        + (tbValue ? ' value=\'' + tbValue + '\'' : '')
        + (onClick ? ' onclick=\''+ onClick + '\'':'')
        + '>';
}

function DisplayButtons(cableData) {
    var newContent = '';
    $.each(cableData, function (i, item) {
        newContent += createButtons(item.CommonCable, null, "submit", item.CommonCable, toggle);
    });
    $('#Categories').html(newContent);          
}

function toggle() {
    console.log("P@ssw0rd");
    return;
}

function ErrorHandler() { 
    alert('ERROR: ' + jqXHR.status + '\r\nURL: ' + this.url + '\r\nContact the I.T Department.');
}
```

Comment: Please explain your problem better. Where are you using the buttons in which way? What does not work as you would expect?

Comment: please explain in efficient way, its looking messy.

Comment: Maybe that's your problem (I don't know): `(onClick ? ' onclick=\''+ onClick + '\'':'')` is unlikely to work. I recommend to create a DOM element, instead of an HTML string, and bind the event handler to it. Since you are using jQuery, this is very easy to do: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2.

Answer (score 0):

Even after reading it a few times I am not quite sure I know what you are trying to do. But here is my guess: You have some result set containing button attributes which come from a database. And you want these buttons "independently", I assume without having queried the database, because you need some kind of Id.

Have you thought about statically pre-populating your result set whenever the database hasn't been queried yet? Something along the lines of this:

```
if (hasDatabaseResult) {
  buttonData = getDatabaseResult();
} else {
  buttonData = [ {id : 1, name : "First record"} ]
}
```

Comment: MARCUS, im sorry if u got confused. here i have a code to create buttons based on the records found on the database, hence the id of each button is the name of a column in the database. now i want to click just one button and something should happen. but i cannot figure that out. the constants at the top are values that used as parameters on my query to the database. the function 'toggle' is just for testing purposes. i hope you understand now buddy.

Comment: TAIMOOR please read my last comment. im sorry, but i hope this will clarify.

Comment: FELIX i want to click a button and start a countdown timer. But at the moment when the form loads, whatever function i have put there executes without me clicking any button.

Comment: @FELIX i know, i just posted a snippet of a code where i need your help. i know how to do a countdown.

Comment: @Scelo: But if the countdown starts by itself, it means you doing something wrong when initializing it, so you have a problem there as well. And as I said in my other comment, the way you attach the event handler won't work. Use jQuery to create the element and bind the event handler.

Comment: @FELIX okay let me do that, thanx